# What does it mean to perform mutex locks functions atomically?

Tags: operating-system, locking, mutex, atomic

It is stated that calls to either acquire() or release() must be performed atomically. What do they mean by that?

```
acquire() {
   while (!available)
      ; /* busy wait */
   available = false;;
}
   do {
      (acquire lock)
         critical section
      (release lock)
         remainder section
   } while (true);

release() {
   available = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `atomic` operation means that either it will be fully completed or not completed at all. The operation cannot be stopped/killed/ended in the **MIDDLE**.

Atomic operations are used in case of multithreaded programming mostly. These operations are used to keep the sanity of critical section/variable sane, as many threads race for their execution.

A good place to read about atomic operations and concurrency in C++ is "Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams

Comment: If word 'this' = `atomic operation` and 'context switch'  = switching of one process to another process in the middle of execution. If you exclusively mean lock acquire and release functions (mentioned in your q), then the answer is almost yes. If you disable context switch then there will be no chance of the running 
 process/thread to switch to another and the mutex lock/unlock will be kind of atomic (no other process could pre-empt the running process)..But the general answer is no. Atomic operations are not limited to mutex lock/unlock operations. There are many other such operations.